# Table border and caption issue for PDF generation in docx4j

Tags: docx4j

I'm having an issue with getting the table caption and border to output in PDF. I'm using docx4j 3.0.0 but I also had the same issue with 2.8.1.

I have a xhtml fragment generated by TinyMCE. I do some processing to get it the way docx4j wants it, and convert it to openXML using XHTMLImporterImpl.
I use the marshaller to get the docx format working and Docx4j.toPDF for the pdf format.
It works for most cases, italics, underline, bold, alignment, images, etc.

When it comes to table caption and border, it works in the docx format, but not the PDF format. It simply excludes the table with these properties. I think xhtml -> openXML is working properly, but the Docx4j.toPDF is not supporting these properties or something. I tried searching the web with no luck. I was wondering if someone already knew about this.

The error I get is

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
at org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyTokenizer.nextColor(PropertyTokenizer.java:239)
at org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyTokenizer.next(PropertyTokenizer.java:175)
at org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyParser.parseProperty(PropertyParser.java:118)
at org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyParser.parse(PropertyParser.java:91)
at org.apache.fop.fo.properties.PropertyMaker.make(PropertyMaker.java:438)
at org.apache.fop.fo.PropertyList.convertAttributeToProperty(PropertyList.java:413)
at org.apache.fop.fo.PropertyList.addAttributesToList(PropertyList.java:321)
at org.apache.fop.fo.FObj.processNode(FObj.java:122)
at org.apache.fop.fo.flow.table.TableFObj.processNode(TableFObj.java:232)
...
Caused by: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception exporting package
at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:79)
at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:467)
at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:477)
```

The openXML looks like this for the table

```
<w:tbl>
<w:tblPr>
<w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
<w:tblCellSpacing w:w="20" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:tblInd w:w="115" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:tblBorders>
<w:top w:val="inset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:left w:val="inset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:bottom w:val="inset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:right w:val="inset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:insideH w:val="none"/>
<w:insideV w:val="none"/>
</w:tblBorders>
</w:tblPr>
<w:tblGrid>
<w:gridCol w:w="1045"/>
<w:gridCol w:w="903"/>
</w:tblGrid>
<w:tr>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
<w:tcW w:w="1045" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:tcBorders>
<w:top w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:left w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:bottom w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:right w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
</w:tcBorders>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:spacing w:after="0"/>
<w:ind w:left="0"/>
<w:jc w:val="left"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:b w:val="false"/>
<w:i w:val="false"/>
<w:color w:val="000000"/>
<w:sz w:val="22"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Col 1</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
<w:tcW w:w="903" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:tcBorders>
<w:top w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:left w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:bottom w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:right w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
</w:tcBorders>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:spacing w:after="0"/>
<w:ind w:left="0"/>
<w:jc w:val="left"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:b w:val="false"/>
<w:i w:val="false"/>
<w:color w:val="000000"/>
<w:sz w:val="22"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Col2</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>
<w:tr>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
<w:tcW w:w="1045" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:tcBorders>
<w:top w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:left w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:bottom w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:right w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
</w:tcBorders>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:spacing w:after="0"/>
<w:ind w:left="0"/>
<w:jc w:val="left"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:b w:val="false"/>
<w:i w:val="false"/>
<w:color w:val="000000"/>
<w:sz w:val="22"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Row1</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
<w:tcW w:w="903" w:type="dxa"/>
<w:tcBorders>
<w:top w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:left w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:bottom w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
<w:right w:val="outset" w:color="#000000" w:sz="8"/>
</w:tcBorders>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p>
<w:pPr>
<w:spacing w:after="0"/>
<w:ind w:left="0"/>
<w:jc w:val="left"/>
</w:pPr>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:b w:val="false"/>
<w:i w:val="false"/>
<w:color w:val="000000"/>
<w:sz w:val="22"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>table</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

I think there's a bug with the default border color going in as #000000 instead of 000000.  Is there a workaround by pre-processing the xhtml?

duplicates question http://www.docx4java.org/forums/pdf-output-f27/tabl-caption-and-border-issue-docx4j-3-0-0-t1763.html

I'll update both when answered

Comment: Jason:

Just pushed the fix for https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues/101 and this.. https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-Impor ... 86b583047d

It will be in 3.0.1, due shortly.

Comment: table caption still doesn't work, but I'm going to work around the issue by preprocessing the html and parse out the caption text and include it as a regular paragraph before the table.